# If I want to run python code that includes modules on another machine that doesn't have python installed, can I do this?

Tags: python, module, scripting

I want to have a usb stick with some of my python scripts, so that I can just take them with me and execute on any machine I am currently using. 
Is there a way to execude python scripts on a machine that doesn't have python installed? I don't want to edit them, just execute.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could use Docker if that's installed. E.g. `docker run python:slim my-script.py` see https://hub.docker.com/_/python?tab=tags

Answer (score 1):

I think for your scenario you may need to create an executable file. See this post here. [standalone executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)